# Random OSError 22 using shutil with unicode path

Tags: python, shutil

I'm currently facing issues using shutil module. I am using the following function to copy files recursively and overwrite other files

```
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    names = os.listdir(src)
    if ignore is not None:
        ignored_names = ignore(src, names)
    else:
        ignored_names = set()

    if not os.path.isdir(dst):  # This one line does the trick
        os.makedirs(dst)
    errors = []
    for name in names:
        if name in ignored_names:
            continue
        srcname = os.path.join(src, name)
        dstname = os.path.join(dst, name)
        try:
            if symlinks and os.path.islink(srcname):
                linkto = os.readlink(srcname)
                os.symlink(linkto, dstname)
            elif os.path.isdir(srcname):
                copytree(srcname, dstname, symlinks, ignore)
            else:
                # Will raise a SpecialFileError for unsupported file types
                shutil.copy2(srcname, dstname)
        # catch the Error from the recursive copytree so that we can
        # continue with other files
        except shutil.Error as err:
            errors.extend(err.args[0])
        except EnvironmentError as why:
            errors.append((srcname, dstname, str(why)))
    try:
        shutil.copystat(src, dst)
    except OSError as why:
        if WindowsError is not None and isinstance(why, WindowsError):
            # Copying file access times may fail on Windows
            pass
        else:
            errors.extend((src, dst, str(why)))
    if errors:
        raise shutil.Error(errors)
```

Because I have got some paths which are longer than the PATH_MAX on Windows (260 characters), I am using '\\?\' at the beginning of my path. Sometimes shutil returns some errors like the following:

```
shutil.Error: [
    ('\\\\?\\F:\\Jenkins_tests\\workspace\\team_workspace_tests\\sources\\master\\distrib\\folders\\file.sch_txt'),
     '\\\\?\\F:\\Jenkins_tests\\workspace\\team_workspace_tests\\sources\\master\\IMAGE\\schema\\sch_0_15.sch_txt',
     "[Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\\\\\\\?\\\\F:\\\\Jenkins_tests\\\\workspace\\\\team_workspace_tests\\\\sources\\\\master\\\\IMAGE\\\\schema\\\\sch_0_15.sch_txt']`
```

But if I relaunch the script, I will have no errors, or an error on another file...

Maybe I made a mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I needed only to remove the hard link before copy the new file. As I have got many workspaces which have a hard link to the same file, the copyfile function try to open in it write mode, if it happens the same time than another workspace, it probably could not work.